# Как реализовать метод kmeans в с#?

Tags: c#, python, кластеризация

Для решения задачи кластеризации маленькой выборки из точек на плоскости ***методом к-средних*** написал вот такой код на питоне:

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

sample=np.array([[0,0], [1,2], [0, 1], [1, 1], [3,0], [4,1], [5,1], [5, 0]])

visualize = plt.scatter(sample[:, 0], sample[:, 1])

#Цетроиды
centers = np.array([[2, -1], [3, 3]])

#Применение KMeans

kmeans_clustering = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init=centers, n_init=10, random_state=1)
kmeans_clustering.fit(sample)


#Находим метки кластеров:
labels = kmeans_clustering.labels_
labels

visualization=plt.scatter(sample[:, 0], sample[:, 1], c=labels)
```

Не подскажете, можно ли так же просто реализовать такую задачу в c#? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, вы не реализовали метод kMeans, а использовали реализацию, которую другие написали и любезно вам предоставили для использования в рамках библиотеки sklearn.

Во-вторых, хотите реализовывать на C# -  реализовывайте. А если хотите опять использовать готовое решение - есть библиотека [ML.Net](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/machinelearning-ai/ml-dotnet) В нем есть разные методы, в том числе методы кластеризации, в том числе kMeans. 
Вот здесь - описание, как пользоваться
https://medium.com/machinelearningadvantage/easy-k-means-clustering-with-c-and-ml-net-7b154ccd219e
Пользуйтесь.

В-третьих, учитесь самостоятельно искать в Гуугл ответы на хотя-бы вот такие, элементарнейшие вопросы.